# Implimenting a ranking algorithm in Django query

Tags: python, django

I currently have upvotes and downvotes stored.  I am trying to make a ranking algorithm as such

```
ranking = log(upvotes - downvotes)
```

But in doing my query in Django I am using `annotate` as such, and am unsure where I would add in the `math.log` to the annotate so it ranks it by log?

Here is the code

```
        defeniciones = Palabra.objects.prefetch_related(
            'tag_set'
        ).filter(
            nombre__iexact=palabra,
            aprobada=True
        ).annotate(total_votes=Count('userUpVotes') - Count('userDownVotes')).order_by('-total_votes')
```

As can be seen here, [https://diccionarioespañol.com/significado/wey/](https://xn--diccionarioespaol-txb.com/significado/wey/) It ranks the 1 upvote 0 downvotes fine.  But then ranks a 6 upvotes, and 1 downvote at the bottom, instead of number 2.

So I think log will fix this, but if not I am unsure how what an equivalent fix would be.

Comment: It doesn't matter: `log(x)` is *monotone*, so ordering by `x` will produce the same results as ordering by `log(x)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My issue becomes then when something has more downvotes than upvotes, it at times ranks higher.  Say 4 downvotes and 2 upvotes.  Rankes higher than something with 2 upvotes and 1 downvote.

Comment: Well that will be the same for both `up - down` as for `log(up-down)`, besides `log(..)` can not deal with negative numbers.

Comment: if a function `f` is *monotonic*, it means that for all `x1` and `x2`, if `x1 <= x2`, then `f(x1) <= f(x2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out, after checking django documenation.  It says [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations-1)

"Combining multiple aggregations with annotate() will yield the wrong results because joins are used instead of subqueries:"

So the soluction was to change to annotate to include `distinct=True` in the Count like such

```
).annotate(total_votes=Count('userUpVotes', distinct=True) - Count('userDownVotes', distinct=True)).order_by('-total_votes')
```